# Securing Pipeline Variables in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I am planning to use a pipeline variable to authenticate a connect-azaccount command in our PS deployment script. However I do not want these credentials just sitting in the open air they don't appear to censor themselves at all. I'm looking for a way to make this more secure so these credentials aren't as easy to access as just checking the pipeline's variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the padlock next to the variables you should be able to obscure the password. Is this what you are looking for?

A more secure option would be storing credentials in Azure Key Vault

Comment: It actually somewhat is, I didn't see that button. We are actually trying to store creds for our deployment script to access the connect-azaccount process so it can then pull from the vault for our actual secrets.

But we've made the decision to convert our pipelines to YAML instead of trying to fool around with the classic ui pipelines anymore.